# Renaming a SAS variable with white spaces and length ge 32 characters

Tags: sas, rename

After importing an Excel-file (with column names given) I get a column whose name is "Transportation Cost [LC/Shipment", the variable's label is "Transportation Cost [LC/Shipment]" (pls note the closing square bracket), which is the right Excel-column name.

I would like to rename "Transportation Cost [LC/Shipment", but without counting the characters. What I have is:

```
Rename 'Transportation Cost [LC/Shipment'n=Ship_Costs;
```

.. which works.

```
Rename 'Transportation Cost [LC/Shipment]'=Ship_Costs;
```

gives an error, because the name length exceeds 32 characters.

How can I use the full Excel-name to rename the variable?

A good solution in my mind would be similar to:

```
Rename Substr('Transportation Cost [LC/Shipment]', 1, 32) = Ship_Costs;
```

because in this case I could use the full == "right" column name.

Additional question: What exactly does the "n" after mean, is it like a Python raw string?

Thx&kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS has two naming conventions. One doesn't allow spaces but the other does and if you enclose the variable in quotes SAS needs a way to tell that's a variable name versus a character string. It does this by adding letters immediately after the quotes, so you're using name literals.

n -> name literal
d -> date literal
t -> time literal
dt -> datetime literal

Unfortunately another naming convention is that names cannot be longer than 32 characters. SAS usually truncates the name if it goes over. You have two options that I can see.

One is to switch the naming schema so SAS imports it and does some of the conversions but you're still stuck cleaning it up a bit. Set the `validvarname` option to V7, the other option is ANY, re-import your data and then try renaming.

```
options validvarname=v7;
```

Second is to use PROC CONTENTS or the explorer, find the truncated name and rename it similar to what you have above.